# Python printing in Russian on a PC using a different locale

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext

I am learning i8N in Python, everything OK with western charsets but I have a problem to verify/test using eastern and oriental charsets. My PCs are set for Italy and Spain so to test other languages I force to set locale by code as one of these:

```
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'German')
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Spanish')
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Italian')
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'French')
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Russian')
```

the first four are working then for those not working as russian I set the default stdout and stderr charsets:

```
...
elif "Russian" in l[0] or "ru_" in l[0]:
    ru = gettext.translation('base', localedir='locales', languages=['ru'])
    ru.install()
    _ = ru.gettext
    import io
    sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
    sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
```

in this way there are no runtime errors but the output does not seems to be russian, this should be the russian translation of "Hello Python!":

ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, Python!

So, I searched the web but I did not find anything useful, I think I missed something...

Comment: interesting perhaps set `export LC_ALL=ru_RU` or `LANG`

Comment: for me LC_ALL=ru_RU returns an error

Comment: Redirect the output into a file and check the length in bytes. If it is 36 bytes, you have a bug in your Python code (try to delete the last two lines?). If it 22 bytes, your terminal is misconfigured.

Comment: seems that it works on every tkinter widget and the problem is on stdout and stderr only. Both tkinter and stdout/stderr are set for utf-8.

Comment: If it is on stdout and stderr only, your terminal is not configured correctly. Essentially, it is a display problem.